# Redirect To Sub Folder By Country

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm trying to separate the shop section of my website into US and UK sections as I offer different products to each country.

I'd like to use a sub folder ie. `/us` or `/uk`, but only when the customer goes into the shop section (clicks on shop, category or product).

I think the best way may be to create a `shop.` subdomain and activate an IP based redirect to the appropriate subfolder once they enter the `shop.` subdomain.

I'd could use a country selector pop-up (no need for redirect by IP) but I don't want two separate websites and I don't want my blog posts to be under the `/us` or `/uk` subfolders.

That's why I want to activate the redirect only when users click on the `shop.` section.

I'm using Worpress so if there are any plugins that would work I could use them.

If I had to use only subfolders (`/shop/uk` , `/product/uk` etc) then I could do that, but I can't find any advice that applies to my specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom post type "shop" and then create a custom taxonomy.
Then add new custom taxonomy for each country and assign it to the custom post type "shop".

Register your custom post type in functions.php like so:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_types', 0 );
function custom_post_types() {

//shops
    register_post_type( 'shops',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Shops' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Shops' ),
                'all_items'  => __( 'All Shops'),
            ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'edit_post'          => 'update_core',
                'read_post'          => 'update_core',
                'delete_post'        => 'update_core',
                'edit_posts'         => 'update_core',
                'edit_others_posts'  => 'update_core',
                'delete_posts'       => 'update_core',
                'publish_posts'      => 'update_core',
                'read_private_posts' => 'update_core'
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array('countries'),
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => false,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
            "rewrite" => array(
                "slug"=>'news/%countries%',
                "with_front" => false
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Then register your custom taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );
function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy('countries', 'shops', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Countries', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'shops', 'with_front' => false)));
 }
```

In order to use %countries%/ in the rewrite rule when registering your custom post type you need to tell WordPress what that means. You do it like so:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_shops_permalinks', 1, 2 );
function wpa_shops_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'shops' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'countries' );
    if( $terms ){
        return str_replace( '%countries%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
    }
}
return $post_link;
}
```